# minimap Drawing issue with graphics in thread

Tags: c#, graphics

I am attempting to create a minimap for an overlay. Currently the radar portion is working, targets rotate around the center point at the correct distance. I am having trouble printing the graphic that holds the minimap to screen. Everything other than the map prints to screen using the SlimDx.Direct3D9 library but based on my research the best way to create sub images based on player location was with graphics and this method avoids the OutOfMemory exception with cloning bitmaps and is more efficient.

```
if (ShowRadar)
{
  //Draw background
  //DrawFilledBox(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 225, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 50, 201f, 201f, Color.DarkOliveGreen, RadarTransparency);
  RadarCenter = new Vector2(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 125, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 125 + 25);
  if (DXTextrureMap != null)
  {
    //Transpose player posistion to map position and create the current mini map image
    x = (int)player_X / 8;// +/- 4000 is max player range /8 = 500 = max map range
    z = (int)player_Z / 8;
    mini = new Rectangle(x, z, 100, 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(originalBitmap);
    g.DrawImage(originalBitmap, mini, new Rectangle((int)this.GameWindowRect.Right - 125, (int)this.GameWindowRect.Top + 125, 100, 100), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

  }//the rest works as it should and displays on screen
  if (RadarCenter.Length() > 0f)
  {
    //Display each entity in correct relational position
    foreach (ENTITY entity in Entity)
    {
      Vector2 pointToRotate = new Vector2(entity.Pos.X, entity.Pos.Z);
      Vector2 vector3 = new Vector2(player_X, player_Z);
      pointToRotate = vector3 - pointToRotate;
      float num30 = pointToRotate.Length() * 0.5f;
      num30 = Math.Min(num30, 90f);
      pointToRotate.Normalize();
      pointToRotate = (Vector2)(pointToRotate * num30);
      pointToRotate += RadarCenter;
      pointToRotate = RotatePoint(pointToRotate, RadarCenter, player_D, true);
      if (entity.Type == 0x04 && RadarPlayers)
      {
        DrawFilledBox(pointToRotate.X, pointToRotate.Y, 3f, 3f, Color.SkyBlue);
      }
      if ((entity.Type == 0x0C || entity.Type == 0x14 || entity.Type == 0x50 || entity.Type == 0x5b) && RadarAggressive)
      {
        DrawFilledBox(pointToRotate.X, pointToRotate.Y, 3f, 3f, Color.Red);
      }
      if ((entity.Type == 0x13 || entity.Type == 0x55) && RadarAnimals)
      {
        DrawFilledBox(pointToRotate.X, pointToRotate.Y, 3f, 3f, Color.LightGreen);
      }
      if ((entity.Type == 0x11 || entity.Type == 0x72 || entity.Type == 0x76) && RadarVehicles)
      {
        DrawFilledBox(pointToRotate.X, pointToRotate.Y, 3f, 3f, Color.HotPink);
      }
    }
  }
  //Draw radar border
  DrawBoxAbs(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 225, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 50, 201f, 201f, 1f, Color.Black);
  //Draw radar axis
  DrawLine(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 125, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 50, this.GameWindowRect.Right - 125, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 251, 1f, Color.Black);
  DrawLine(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 225, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 150, this.GameWindowRect.Right - 24, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 150, 1f, Color.Black);
  //Center point
  DrawFilledBox(RadarCenter.X - 1f, RadarCenter.Y - 1f, 3f, 3f, Color.White);
}
```

What is the correct way to print my graphic?

Answer (score 0):

Makes more sense when you realize a graphic draws on the image it grabs, also had to dispose of some elements. Time to make it rotate then perhaps add headings.

```js
if (DXTextrureMap != null)
{ 
  DXSprite.Begin(SpriteFlags.None);
  //Transpose player posistion to map position and create the current mini map image
  x = (int)player_X / 4;// +/- 4000 is max player range and  /4 = 1000 = max map range
  z = (int)player_Z / 4;
  mini = new Rectangle(x-78, z-78, 157, 157);
  croppedBitmap = new Bitmap(200, 200);
  using (Graphics grD = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap))
  {
    grD.DrawImage(originalBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, 157, 157), mini, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
  }
  //croppedBitmap = Copy(originalBitmap, mini);
  using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream())//s is a MemoryStream
  {
    croppedBitmap.Save(s, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //must do this, or error is thrown in next line
    currentMinimap = Texture.FromStream(DXDevice, s);
    s.Dispose();
  }

  //croppedImage.Dispose();
  DXSprite.Draw(currentMinimap, new Vector3(100f, 100f, 0f), new Vector3(this.GameWindowRect.Right - 125, this.GameWindowRect.Top + 135, 0f), Color.White);
  DXSprite.End();
  currentMinimap.Dispose();
}
```